# Проблема с ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, linux

Я установил ffmpeg на linux сервер, и хочу конвертировать видео для всех броузеров, но оно не работает на ipad, iphone, IE9. Это команда с помощю которой конвертирую видео

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -b 250k -bt 50k -acodec libfaac -ab 56k -ac 2 -s 480x320 output
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте задать расширение выходному файлу output.mp4